# Expression 4 vs SharePoint designer 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, design

A general question. Is there any reason to use Expression Web 4 instead of SharePoint designer 2010 for creating SharePoint master pages and page layouts?

I have it installed right now, but I don't really know the benefit of using it. (Not a designer here, just a regular programmer + Power user but responsible for implementing one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really.  Expression is not "SharePoint aware" and it will not give you any SharePoint Intellisense functionality.  It's best to use SharePoint Designer with the options you specified, Visual Studio would be equally viable.